# How to pass variable to functional component already having a variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I have a child functional component here(CommaFunc(e)) which has to be called with a variable of event for further processing, now what I need to do and I seem to can't, is return one of the variables declared in the CommaFunc child component(realOutput) to the AddCommaToNumber parent component (maybe as props?)

Where I called the parent component:

```
export default class home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AddCommaToNumber />
    )
  }
}
```

The parent component(AddCommaToNumber.js), and where I called the child component:

```
function AddCommaToNumber() {
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

return (
    <div>
        <input
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => { CommaFunc(e); setValue(e.target.value); }}
        type="text"
        />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The child component(commaFunc.js): (I need to somehow pass this `realOutput` to the AddCommaToNumber component)

```
export default function(e) {
    let realOutput = 100;
}
```

Any hints or help is appreciated!